# Responsive - resize DIV width while maintaining height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to figure out how best to handle the following case of responsive design.

I need the text box to the side of the beer image to grow / shrink it's width, but maintain the height to match the height of the beer image.  At a certain breakpoint I will have that text box move under the beer image.

```html
.beer-content {
  padding: 50px 68px;
}
.amber-beer {
  float: left;
}
.amber-beer img {
  margin-top: -21px;
}
.amber-beer-text {
  float: left;
  height: 374px;
  background: #f8eddf;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  max-width: 725px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="beer-content">
    <div class="amber-beer"><img src="_img/beer-amber-ale.png" alt="Amber Ale" /></div>
    <div class="amber-beer-text">
        <p class="beer-title"><img src="_img/beer-title-bars.png" alt="" /> Amber</p>
        <p>Amber beers are a style that fall between light pale ales and brown ales. They are generally categorized as pale ale. This beer is dark amber in colour, has traces of citrus in its aroma, and one can pick up hints of caramel and coffee in its full bodied flavour. Though it is fairly well hopped (32ibu), the robust character and complexity of this fine amber turns it into nectar of the gods that no serious beer drinker should pass up.</p>
        <div class="beer-circle">
            <span>OG</span>
            1052
        </div>
        <div class="beer-circle">
            <span>ABV</span>
            5%
        </div>
        <div class="beer-circle">
            <span>SRM</span>
            12
        </div>
        <div class="beer-circle">
            <span>IBU</span>
            32
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the fixed `height` and add a `padding` for the bottom as well. And add `min-height` if you want a minimum height to match the image's height.

```
.amber-beer-text {
    float: left;
    min-height: 374px;
    background: #f8eddf;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    max-width: 725px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't cause the text box to grow / shrink width wise though.  It just stays the same width until it breaks under the image.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be rough, but did You considered write it with CSS Flexbox?
Try this (with YOUR small adjustments):

```
<style> 
    .beer-content {
          display: flex;
          padding: 50px 68px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          flex-direction: row;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
     }
     .amber-beer {
     }
     .amber-beer img {
        margin-top: -21px;
     }
     .amber-beer-text {
        height: 372px;
        background: #f8eddf;
        margin: 0 0 0 20px;
        max-width: 725px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 18px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

     }

     .amber-beer-text .circles{
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
     }

    .amber-beer-text .circles .beer-circle{
        background: url("beer-circle.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        width: 55px;
        height: 55px;
}
</style> 
<div class="beer-content">

            <div class="amber-beer"><img src="beer-amber-ale.png" alt="Amber Ale" /></div>
            <div class="amber-beer-text">
                <p class="beer-title"><img src="beer-title-bars.png" alt="" /> Amber</p>
                <p>Amber beers are a style that fall between light pale ales and brown ales. They are generally categorized as pale ale. This beer is dark amber in colour, has traces of citrus in its aroma, and one can pick up hints of caramel and coffee in its full bodied flavour. Though it is fairly well hopped (32ibu), the robust character and complexity of this fine amber turns it into nectar of the gods that no serious beer drinker should pass up.</p>
                <div class="circles">
                    <div class="beer-circle">
                        <span>OG</span>
                        1052
                    </div>
                    <div class="beer-circle">
                        <span>ABV</span>
                        5%
                    </div>
                    <div class="beer-circle">
                        <span>SRM</span>
                        12
                    </div>
                    <div class="beer-circle">
                        <span>IBU</span>
                        32
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If You need clarifications, I can help You.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this by removing the "float: left" from .amber-beer-text .

The issue now is that I've lost the space between the beer image and the text box.  I can add padding to the text to get it pushed over to the right, but would rather have a way to maintain the space between the two boxes.

Any ideas?